# cleveref and amsthm -- incorrect environment name

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, theorems, cleveref, amsthm

I have `theorem` environments that have the same theoremstyle which I define through `amsthm`. I want them all to share the same counter. This way, a lemma that follows theorem 1.2.6 will have the number 1.2.7. I would like to use `cleveref` to refer to this environments. I use the `memoir` documentclass.

However, the output does not correctly reference the environment name. Does this have to do with the fact that I use the optional `[theorem]` in the `\newtheorem{lemma}` definition?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Defining a theorem style that has bold head and italic body
\newtheoremstyle{italic}{5pt}{5pt}{\itshape}{}{}{}{.5em}
{\bfseries{\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}.}\thmnote{~\textnormal{(#3)}}}

\theoremstyle{italic}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}\label{lem1}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

\cref{thm1} \cref{lem1}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Desired output**

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just need to move the definitions of your theorem-like environments to *after* the loading of `cleveref` package:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

% Defining a theorem style that has bold head and italic body
\newtheoremstyle{italic}{5pt}{5pt}{\itshape}{}{}{}{.5em}
{\bfseries{\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}.}\thmnote{~\textnormal{(#3)}}}

\theoremstyle{italic}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}\label{lem1}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

\cref{thm1} \cref{lem1}

\end{document}
```

See section 14.1 Non-bugs of the [`cleveref` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en).

As usual remember that `cleveref` should be loaded as the last package in your preamble, see section 13 Interaction with Other Packages in the manual.  In particular, it has to come after later than the loading of `amsthm` in this example.