# appear the word "Lemma " automatically

Tags: ref

If we want to refer to "Lemma 3.4", we can write  " Lemma \ref{number9}". Is there a command that the word "Lemma" or "Theorem" or ... appear automatic too? (i.e we write ... and in pdf appear "Lemma 3.4")

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes it is possible. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281224/121799.

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, in my latex, the command "\cref" is enough.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question since the problem in that question was that `cleveref` was loaded after the theorem environments were declared. It is likely a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5767/156366) though.